# HDD slow formatting usefulness

Tags: hard-drive, formatting

I would have a noob question.

I bought a 16TB hard drive. Is it useful to do the slow formatting proposed by Windows before using it ?

I'm asking this because I've already had bad sectors even on a new disk.

Does this slow formatting of Windows (the one proposed by "right clic/format") put the bad sectors aside, or does it bring nothing more than the fast formatting which just erases the FAT?

On the other hand, when the disk falls on a faulty sector, is it put aside, or should the drive have been formatted before?

Answer (score 1):

> "Is it useful to do the slow formatting proposed by Windows before using it ?"

No, I use to do it on drives back in the day when they were small to qualify them (be sure no bad sectors) but is of no use these days on new drives, but is still useful on used drives.

> "right click/format") put the bad sectors aside"

Yes, but the drive firmware does this automatically when it hits a bad sector.

Comment: Thank you for your response. More precisely, when the firmware hits a bad sector when writing on the drive, are the written data lost, or is this sector put aside without data loss ?

Comment: It attempts recovery and writes it to a new spare sector. I use this utility for superior data recovery of bad sectors, not free though, just the best>>>>>>>https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm

Comment: Thank you. And even more precisely, when the firmware hits a bad sector that has never been written yet, on a brand new hdd just bought, is the written data lost, or does the firmware put this sector aside _**before**_ writting the data ?

Comment: When it writes the data it also reads it after the write, so if it is a bad sector it moves to the next free sector and tries again.

Comment: That's the precise information I needed. So I understand that when you buy a new virgin HDD, there is no need to low-level (slowly) format it because if a bad sector is found, no data will be lost when writing on it. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

> I'm asking this because I've already had bad sectors even on a new disk.

You should not have bad sectors on a new disk. 
If that happens you either have no new disk or the disk was treated inadequately.

> On the other hand, when the disk falls on a faulty sector, is it put aside, or should the drive have been formatted before?

The disk behaviour varies as function of the operation mode.
If the disk is ordered to read a faulty sector it hangs. It increases the "pending sector" count. A retry of the read operation may perhaps give a valid read result.
If the disk is ordered to write a faulty sector and that fails the sector will be remapped if there is still a sector in the spare pool. In this case you will see an increase in the  "reallocated sector" SMART parameter.